# How to define a custom loss function properly?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, loss-function

Question: How should I define a custom loss function that matches with the default value of the learning rate?

It is obvious that defining a proper loss function is vital for training a neural network.

On the other hand, learning rate is an important parameter that must be set properly.

As I know, loss function and learning rate are tightly related because they directly determine new values of the network weights:

`w_new = w_old - learning_rate * (gradient_of_loss w.r.t. w)`

For example one may choose the following loss function:
`loss_1 = || y_pred - y_true||^2_2`

But another chooses the following:
`loss_2 = (1/2)|| y_pred - y_true||^2_2`

In many neural network/deep learning framework, the value of learning rate is set as default. So using default learning rate, the effective learning rate in latter loss function is half of the former. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: learning rate is not the properties or attributes of loss function but of optimizers or other backpropagation techniques. So,essentialy you'd have to implement backpropagation step.

Comment: Tensorflow uses automatic differentiation so you can define your loss function however you wish (as long as it's differentiable). A good learning rate depends on so many factors. Try different values say between [0.1,0.001] and see what works.